# how can i compile node js Example file

Tags: node.js

i have configure nodejs successfully..on windows with help of cygwin i flow the instruction of github.. now i want to know how could i compile hello world example with node js...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run the server, put the code into a file example.js and execute it with the node program:

```
$ node example.js
```

Comment: thanks its work ..i am using wrong way...one more question how can i send data from client side on my server and retrieve from server.....is there any tutorial that can help mee

Comment: if you go on the nodejs.org website there's a sample on there front page !

Comment: thanks,how can i make the client for the nodejs....can browser compile nodejs code ,can you tell me any example that send the data to the server and server response against data....